# Log transformation of $e^x$ and lognormal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I have the following function: $e^x$ whereby $x$ is a random variable following the distribution $x\sim \mathcal{N}(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2},\sigma^2)$.

Can someone explain me why, if I take the log-transformation of $e^x$, I should get $ln(e^x)=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+x$ whereby $x\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$? Is this an error? I really do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used $x$ twice, which may be confusing.   So let's use $Y$ initially and $Z$ later and rewrite your question:

> I have the following function: $e^Y$ whereby $Y$ is a random variable following the distribution $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2},\sigma^2)$.
>
> Can someone explain me why, if I take the log-transformation of $e^Y$, I should get $\ln(e^Y)=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+Z$ whereby $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$?

The simple answer is that $\ln(e^Y)=Y$.  Then $\ln(e^Y)=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+Z$ implies $Z=Y+\frac{\sigma^2}{2} = Y- \mathbb E[Y]$ so has a mean of $0$ and the same variance and is still normally distributed, giving $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.  This all makes more sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, but what I don't understand is why $ln(e^Y)=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+Z$ is the equivalent of writing $ln(e^Y)=Y$.

Comment: @AndreasTT Because $Z=Y+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$